# Troubleshoot connecting client to server in java

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address

I have been having this problem for some time now and although my efforts and my friends help I can't seem to get past this problem .

My problem is I am trying to establish a connection between client and a server using sockets its very common actually, but for some reason client can't seem to connect to the server don't know why , here is my attempts to solve the problem

1- I used http://portforward.com/ to open the used port on my router which is of type "zhone"
2- I changed the port multiple times and every time I used PFPortChecker to see if my port is open

my code is fairly simple it opens server and when client connects to it , the server sends the date and time

my server code looks like this

```
public class DateServer {

    /** Runs the server. */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(6780);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

my client code looks like this

```
public class DateClient {

    /** Runs the client as an application. First it displays a dialog box asking for the IP address or hostname of a host running the date server, then connects to it and displays the date that it serves. */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //I used my serverAddress is my external ip address 
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 6780);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

even though I continued my attempts

3- I closed my firewall just in case

4- I added connection time out in my server socket

with all my attempts I always get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at DateClient.main(DateClient.java:13)
```

note that DateClient.java:13 is this line Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 6780);

please help me with this problem , thanks in advance

Comment: What is your serverAddress in your client? What is your server address?

Comment: Try checking if your port is open with another program then PFPortChecheker, like this site: [link](http://www.canyouseeme.org/). It needs some service to run on that port, though

Comment: my server address is my external address which is for example shown in this link [link](http://www.canyouseeme.org/)

Comment: @Creator13 I checked ur link and its said the port is open and not blocked

Comment: Are you running client on computer with external IP.

Comment: Try to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1) instead of your external IP address. Worked for me

Comment: @Nikolai yes I run the client on computer with external IP

Comment: Firewall. It's always the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

- Close the PrintWriter on the server side
- Be sure you use localhost (try 127.0.0.1) as the server address. Depending on how are you connecting the Internet, the external Internet address (as shown by various "get my ip" tools on the web) may be different from the actual address to that your network interface is configured and not work from the same machine. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT#Methods_of_port_translation).

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code. First, localhost (127.0.0.1) could solve your problem. On the other side, I changed the ports and IP to my own, and it just works fine (even my external IP). So probably there is something wrong with your port/IP.

- In case it works using localhost, your IP was not the right one, or something on your computer is blocking external connections.
  Your client code should look like this, for some reason `new Socket(String host, int port)` wont work.

  ```
  public class DateClient {

  /** Runs the client as an application. First it displays a dialog box asking for the IP address or hostname of a host running the date server, then connects to it and displays the date that it serves. */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      //I used my serverAddress is my external ip address 
      InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(String host);
      Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 6780);
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
      String answer = input.readLine();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
      System.exit(0);
  }
  ```

  }
- If it doesn't work using localhost, your port is not forwarded correctly. Try to log in to your router and forward the port from there.

And indeed, like @Audrius Meškauskas said, you might want to close your PrintWriter on your server, right before closing your ServerSockect `listener`.

Comment: I tried closing the print writer and double checked my external ip , all no use , still running only on my external host

Comment: no its the same as the sample code I provide Socket = new Socket(ip,port)

Comment: ok how about other option I already tried heroku , and run its sample program to know how to deploy the server code ,I deployed the  server code but I could not run the server code on heroku till now, can any one guide where to get specific details of this procedure , perhaps I did some thing wrong

Comment: I just discovered something what if I have multiple pcs running on the same router , and I just checked their external ip addresses and its all the same, so I am guessing it could make some conflicts , does anyone have any idea how to fix this?!

Comment: That doesn't matter. When it tries to connect to your server, it looks for the only client running on port 6780 in your whole network. If you try to start a server with the same port on two computers, it will throw a BindException. That can't be a problem.

Comment: And I edited my answer. If you do it that way, I'm convinced it will work. (So you add a line `InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");`)

Comment: By default, the router does not forward any external calls into the local network as it is not aware about the services running at different ports on various computers there. The router only forwards calls from internal network to outside, and then can transfer reply correctly as it knows the originator of the call. On some more advanced routers the forwarding you need may be manually configured.